# Is it possible to load a C++ shared library to Mathematica 8.0?

Tags: c++, mathematica-8, mathlink

I'm trying to load a C++ function compiled to a shared library from Mathematica 8.0. I did manage to use a C function using MathLink but MathLink does not seem to support C++ functions. So I tried to create a shared library and load it through LibraryLink, but LibraryFunctionLoad does not seem to be able to load a C++ function. Does anyone managed to use a C++ function within Mathematica, and if so, what are the tricks that one have to do to make it work?

Comment: Can you wrap the C++ library in a C library?

Comment: Can you recompile the C++ with `extern "C"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `C++` code uses mangling of the symbols being exported.

This encodes the namespace, classname, return type, name and parameters as part of the exported symbol. This means that a function called:

```
int hello(int x, int y, int z)
```

exports as something like:

```
_Z5helloiii
```

This was done on g++ on linux, windows has a different mangling scheme.

In order to ensure that functions are exported in a C compatible way, you wrap the function in the `extern "C"` mechanism, which causes it to be exported in a form that is compatible with MathLink

so you use the following in the header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int hello(int x, int y, int z);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

As long as you `#include` this header in your `C++` implementation, it should link correctly with `MathLink`